# Простой слайдер со стрелками

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

http://www.srtcoin.io/en ребята как сделать такой же слайдер как на этом сайте. могу заморочиться с ксс и бутстрапом,но не думаю,что оно того стоит. [image: сам слайдер]
 если кто нибудь еще и скинет ресурсы,где подробно описаны все слайдеры(подобные) .процесс их создания и примеры буду рад

p.s якорные ссылки плавно передвигаются тоже благодаря джаваскрипту?
p.s.s не смог открыть с сайта код джаваскрипта,где его найти?

Answer (score 1):

Этот слайдер самый лучший:
http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/
Оч простой и примеры всех видов сладеров есть) очень гибкий